# Header not aligned in center

Tags: css

I have a pop up window with a close button, a header, and some content. The content is all centered, but the header is pushed to the left for some reason. I think it is pushed to the left because of the close button.  Can someone help me?

Here is the css code. Everything is aligned properly except the header.

```css
.popUpModal{
    display: none;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.popUpContent{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8%;

    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: center;

    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
}

.close{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;

    font-size: 40px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.trainingPopUpHeader{
    margin-top: 4%;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.trainingPopUpDescription{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.trainingStepList{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 4%;
}

.trainingVideo{
    height: 35%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
   <div class="popUpModal" id=popUpModal>
        
        <div class="popUpContent">
            <div class="close">+</div>
            <h1 class="trainingPopUpHeader">How to Change Labels</h1>
            <div  class="trainingPopUpDescription">
                <p>When the labeler machine runs out of labels, it is up to one of the associates to 
      replace the labels
                 so the machine can continue running. It is important to be quick and accurate when 
     reloading the labels. 
                 Watch the video and read the step-by-step instructions to complete this training.    
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class= "trainingStepList">
                <p>
                    1. Pull off used back paper <br>
                    2. Find new pack of front & back labels <br>
                    3. Insert front labels onto the front left roller <br>
                    4. Insert back labels onto the front right roller <br>

                </p>
            </div>
            <video class="trainingVideo" controls>
                <source src="testVid.mp4">
            </video>

                            <!--add video element-->
                            <!--add step by step instructions-->
                                            
            <!--need a text header, a step by step instruction list, a video, and an input form for name-->
        </div>  
   

    </div>
```

[image: header pushed to left]

Is there some reason my header is being pushed to the left by the close button?

Comment: Your layout doesn't seem to be reproducible with the code snippet provided.

Comment: Are you using any external stylsheets i.e. bootstrap or something? The code you provided does not reproduce the image you shared

Comment: @BeerusDev Thats probably my fault, I did not include the css code for all of the pop up content, just the header and close button.

Comment: Could you check my edit and include all the relevant code constituting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Thanks!

Comment: There's no `display: flex` in your CSS. So, how can you set `justify-content` and `align-items`?

Answer (score 1):

Next time please use snippets

https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-voice-9s0zu

For the sake of visiblity I've changed with of the popup from 50 to 80%

Your `close` button is at fault. Precisely, `float`. You might be mistaken that it's being removed from the flow of the website, but it's not a case entirely. It's being shifted to the edge of the container or to another floated component and thus is still taking some space. So now, width of top of your popup contains both `header` and floated `close` button. You probably are looking for `position: absolute` paired with `right: x px` for this application

Comment: thanks, King. Everyone always tells me to use snippets, but im not sure what that means. I included portions of my css and html code in the post, is that not what a snippet is?

Comment: Initially it was just bits of code, nicely formatted. Now, eddited, it's providing working example where you can click 'run code snippet' to view working example. Thats what we mean when we ask for a snippet. You can create it by clicking <> button in editor, next to `add picture` icon

Comment: @NickJohnson There is a <> icon when you are posting question where there is a UI for you to put your html, css and js tool. StackOverflow will render the example for you.